# add bibtex to a xelatex report document

Tags: xetex, natbib

I have to send my thesis today, and I haven't slept for a while. I'm trying to add my bibliography with a bib file. With online tutorials, I used endnote to make my useref.txt and then in my tex file wrote this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,BCOR=.7cm,headsepline,bibliography=totoc]{report}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
...
...
...
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{useref}
```

but when I run `Xelatex+MakeIndex+Bibtex`

I get `Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.`
with textify.log stating

```
2022-03-13 13:10:12,718+0330 INFO  texify.core - start process: miktex-bibtex.exe thesis
2022-03-13 13:10:13,064+0330 FATAL texify.core - BibTeX failed for some reason.
2022-03-13 13:10:13,065+0330 FATAL texify.core - Data: 
2022-03-13 13:10:13,065+0330 FATAL texify.core - Source: Programs\MiKTeX\texify\mcd.cpp:1331
2022-03-13 13:10:13,070+0330 FATAL texify - BibTeX failed for some reason.
2022-03-13 13:10:13,070+0330 FATAL texify - Info: 
2022-03-13 13:10:13,070+0330 FATAL texify - Source: Programs\MiKTeX\texify\mcd.cpp
2022-03-13 13:10:13,070+0330 FATAL texify - Line: 1331
```

I know this might be a repeated question, but I can't figure out what is wrong. Plz, help me!
this is my full [code](https://github.com/woreom/thesis)

Comment: you haven't tested your bibliography at all until submission day? start by renaming `useref.txt` to `useref.bib` so bibtex sees it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I actually had to overhaul the reference section. Changing it to useref.txt results in the same error

Comment: don't use texify. Run xelatex then bibtex then xelatex. try to produce a small inline example here, I doubt anyone is going to eun your entire github project.

Comment: texify error messages are famously unhelpful. You usually get much more useful messages by running the required programs (XeLaTeX, BibTeX, XeLaTeX, XeLaTeX) yourself. As David says a first obvious error is the file extension of your bibliography file. It is called `useref.txt`, but the bibliography file must have the file extension `.bib`, so you should rename it to `useref.bib`.

Comment: A short look at your bibliography file suggests that a number of references have incorrectly formatted `author` fields. Regardless of the desired output all names must be separated with `and` in the source. `;` and `,` are not valid ways to separate different names (e.g. `RN13`, `RN18`, `RN25`).

Answer (score 2):

A comment up front: If an online tutorial you've come across claims that it's ok to use the extension `.txt` for bib files, then that should be immediate cause to stop using that tutorial immediately. To work with BibTeX, the filename extension *must* be `.bib`. **No exception.**

When I try to generate a test bibliography by running the following program through XeLaTeX and then BibTeX:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,BCOR=.7cm,headsepline,bibliography=totoc]{report}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib} % "sort&compress" option doen't work if there is no 'author' or 'key' field.
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\usepackage{xurl} % <-- for typesetting contents of 'url' fields

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{useref}  % filename extension _must_ be .bib, not .txt
\end{document}
```

BibTeX crashes after encountering 233 [!!] syntax errors. Not bad for a bibliography that contains only 52 entries...

---

Some of the most serious errors concern the `author` fields. For instance,

```
   author = {Alex Graves, Greg Wayne, Malcolm Reynolds, Tim Harley, 
   Ivo Danihelka, Agnieszka Grabska-Barwińska, Sergio Gómez Colmenarejo, 
   Edward Grefenstette, Tiago Ramalho, John Agapiou, 
   Adrià Puigdomènech Badia, Karl Moritz Hermann, Yori Zwols, 
   Georg Ostrovski, Adam Cain, Helen King, Christopher Summerfield, 
   Phil Blunsom, Koray Kavukcuoglu & Demis Hassabis },
```

is **completely and utterly wrong**. BibTeX uses the keyword `and` to separate authors in the `author field`. To use `,`, `;` or `&` as the separator is a plain and simple error. The correct author field should be

```
   author = {Alex Graves and Greg Wayne and Malcolm Reynolds and Tim Harley and 
   Ivo Danihelka and Agnieszka Grabska-Barwińska and Sergio Gómez Colmenarejo and 
   Edward Grefenstette and Tiago Ramalho and John Agapiou and
   Adrià Puigdomènech Badia and Karl Moritz Hermann and Yori Zwols and 
   Georg Ostrovski and Adam Cain and Helen King and Christopher Summerfield and 
   Phil Blunsom and Koray Kavukcuoglu and Demis Hassabis},
```

Similarly, you must replace

```
   author = {Ramachandran, Prajit; Parmar, Niki; Vaswani, Ashish; 
   Bello, Irwan; Levskaya, Anselm; Shlens, Jonathon},
```

with

```
   author = {Ramachandran, Prajit and Parmar, Niki and Vaswani, Ashish and 
   Bello, Irwan and Levskaya, Anselm and Shlens, Jonathon},
```

Moreover, using "et al." in the `author` field is improper as well. Do please replace

```
   author = {Guohui Chuai, Qi Liu et al.},
```

with

```
   author = {Guohui Chuai and Qi Liu and others},
```

Here, `others` is a keyword to denote a truncated list.

---

A second serious syntax error concerns the line

```
url = {https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jAhjPd4uNFY\&t=122s}{\url{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jAhjPd4uNFY\&t=122s},
```

Do *not* "escape" `&`; instead, load the `xurl` package. The correct field should be

```
url = {https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jAhjPd4uNFY&t=122s},
```

---

Then there's the issue that lots of entries -- 20 of them, to be exact -- are *missing* an author field. That is bad because the `plainnat` bibliography style sorts all entries alphbetically. I can't help you with backfilling the appropriate `author` fields.

Finally, BibTeX also issues lots of warning messages because you appear to use the `@article` entry type as the default entry type. Please take note of the fact that the `@article` type should be used exclusively for pieces published in scholarly journals. In the `plainnat` bib style, the `@article` entry type has four *required* fields: `author`, `title`, `journal`, and `year`. I suggest you use `@misc` for all those entries which clearly aren't journal articles.

---

---

The following redacted version of the `useref.bib` file -- again, do note the use of the `.bib` extension -- should not create any error messages. Do please try to work on getting rid of many of as many of the issues that cause warning messages as possible.

```
@misc{RN29,
   title = {All you need about {CRISPR}},
   url = {https://www.addgene.org/guides/crispr/},
   type = {Web Page}
}
@misc{RN26,
   title = {{CHOPCHOP} v3: expanding the {CRISPR} web toolbox beyond genome editing},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
@misc{RN28,
   title = {{CHOPCHOP}: a {CRISPR/Cas9} and {TALEN} web tool for genome editing},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
@misc{RN44,
   title = {CRISPR},
   volume = {2022},
   number = {01/12},
   url = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRISPR},
   type = {Web Page}
}
@misc{RN31,
   title = {{DNA}},
   volume = {2022},
   number = {01/14},
   url = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA},
   type = {Web Page}
}
@misc{RN35,
   title = {First genetically modified animal},
   volume = {2022},
   number = {10/16},
   url = {https://www.pnas.org/content/71/4/1250?tab=author-info},
   type = {Web Page}
}
@misc{RN36,
   title = {First {GM} patent},
   volume = {2022},
   number = {01/16},
   url = {https://patents.google.com/patent/US4259444},
   type = {Web Page}
}
@misc{RN49,
   title = {Genetic Engineering Will Change Everything Forever---{CRISPR}},
   volume = {2022},
   number = {01/14},
   url = {https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jAhjPd4uNFY&t=122s},
   type = {Web Page}
}
@misc{RN42,
   title = {Glowing fish},
   volume = {2022},
   number = {01/16},
   url = {https://www.glofish.com},
   type = {Web Page}
}
@misc{RN39,
   title = {{GMOs}},
   volume = {2022},
   number = {01/16},
   url = {https://th.schattauer.de/contents/archive/issue/721/manuscript/9641.html},
   type = {Web Page}
}
@misc{RN30,
   title = {Good Overview by {Wired}},
   url = {https://www.wired.com/2015/07/crispr-dna-editing-2/},
   type = {Web Page}
}
@misc{RN47,
   title = {{HIV} Genes Have Been Cut Out of Live Animals Using {CRISPR}},
   volume = {2022},
   number = {01/16},
   url = {https://time.com/4340722/hiv-removed-using-crispr/},
   type = {Web Page}
}
@misc{RN34,
   title = {Inserting {DNA} snippets into organisms},
   volume = {2022},
   number = {01/16},
   url = {http://www.genomenewsnetwork.org/resources/timeline/1977_Gilbert.php},
   type = {Web Page}
}
@misc{RN1,
   title = {{ParsiLaTeX}},
   url = {http://parsilatex.com/site/},
   type = {Multimedia Application}
}
@misc{RN33,
   title = {Radiation research},
   url = {https://www.amusingplanet.com/2013/03/atomic-gardening-breeding-plants-with.html},
   type = {Journal Article},
}
@misc{RN2,
   title = {Selective Breeding},
   volume = {2022},
   number = {01/12},
   url = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plant_breeding},
   type = {Web Page}
}
@misc{RN32,
   title = {Understanding {DNA}},
   volume = {2022},
   number = {01/14},
   url = {https://medlineplus.gov/genetics/understanding/basics/dna/},
   type = {Web Page}
}
@misc{RN53,
   title = {{Gene SnipperTM Cas9 Nickase (H840A)}},
   url = {https://www.biovision.com/documentation/datasheets/M1098.pdf},
   year = {2016},
   type = {Chart or Table}
}
@misc{RN50,
   title = {Building Blocks of the Genetic Code},
   url = {https://www.ashg.org/discover-genetics/building-blocks/},
   year = {2019},
   type = {Chart or Table}
}
@misc{RN52,
   title = {What is the Difference Between {ZFN TALEN} and {CRISPR}},
   url = {https://www.differencebetween.com/what-is-the-difference-between-zfn-talen-and-crispr/},
   year = {2021},
   type = {Chart or Table}
}
@article{RN12,
   author = {Alex Graves and Greg Wayne and Malcolm Reynolds and Tim Harley and Ivo Danihelka and Agnieszka Grabska-Barwińska and Sergio Gómez Colmenarejo and Edward Grefenstette and Tiago Ramalho and John Agapiou and Adrià Puigdomènech Badia and Karl Moritz Hermann and Yori Zwols and Georg Ostrovski and Adam Cain and Helen King and Christopher Summerfield and Phil Blunsom and Koray Kavukcuoglu and Demis Hassabis },
   title = {Hybrid computing using a neural network with dynamic external memory},
   journal = {Nature},
   volume = 538,
   number = 7626,
   pages = { 471–476},
   DOI = {10.1038/nature20101},
   year = {2016},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
@misc{RN51,
   author = {Allison, Hilary},
   title = {The Differences Between {DNA} and {RNA}},
   url = {https://www.thoughtco.com/dna-versus-rna-608191},
   year = {2020},
   type = {Chart or Table}
}
@misc{RN3,
   author = {Doudna, Jennifer},
   title = {{TED} Talk},
   month = sep,
   year = {2015},
   type = {Podcast}
}
@misc{RN23,
   author = {Florian Heigwer and Grainne Kerr and Michael Boutros},
   title = {{E-CRISP}: fast {CRISPR} target site identification },
   type = {Journal Article}
}
@misc{RN40,
   author = {G. Bruening and J. M. Lyons},
   title = {The case of the {FLAVR SAVR} tomato},
   url = {https://calag.ucanr.edu/Archive/?article=ca.v054n04p6},
   year = {2000},
   type = {Web Page}
}
@misc{RN21,
   author = {Guohui Chuai and Qi Liu and others},
   title = {{DeepCRISPR}: optimized {CRISPR} guide {RNA} design by deep learning},
   year = {2018},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
 @inproceedings{RN10,
    author="Blockeel, Hendrik",
    editor="Sammut, Claude and Webb, Geoffrey I.",
    title ="Hypothesis Space",
    booktitle="Encyclopedia of Machine Learning",
    year  ="2010",
    publisher="Springer",
    address="Boston, MA",
    pages={511--513},
    doi  ={10.1007/978-0-387-30164-8_373},
    url  ={https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-30164-8_373}
 }
@article{RN4,
   author = {Ishino, Y. and Shinagawa, H. and Makino, K. and Amemura, M. and Nakata, A.},
   title = {Nucleotide sequence of the iap gene, responsible for alkaline phosphatase isozyme conversion in {Escherichia} coli, and identification of the gene product},
   journal = {Journal of Bacteriology},
   volume = {169},
   pages = {5429–5433},
   year = {1987},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
@inproceedings{RN15,
   author = {Jaegle, Andrew and Gimeno, Felix and Brock, Andrew and Zisserman, Andrew and Vinyals, Oriol and Carreira, Joao},
   title = {Perceiver: General Perception with Iterative Attention},
   booktitle={Proceedings of the 38th International Conference on Machine Learning},
   year = {2021},
   xtype = {Journal Article}
}
@article{RN22,
   author = {Jean-Paul Concordet and Maximilian H{\"a}ussler},
   title = {{CRISPOR}: intuitive guide selection for {CRISPR/Cas9} genome editing experiments and screens},
   journal = {Nucleic Acids Research},
   volume = {46},
   number = {W1},
   pages = {W242--W245},
   DOI = {10.1093/nar/gky354},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
@article{RN24,
   author = {Jeongbin Park and Sangsu Bae and Jin-Soo Kim},
   title = {{Cas-Designer}: a web-based tool for choice of {CRISPR-Cas9} target sites},
   journal = {Bioinformatics},
   DOI = {10.1093/bioinformatics/btv537},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
@article{RN37,
   author = {Johnson, I. S.},
   title = {Human insulin from recombinant {DNA} technology},
   journal = {Science},
   DOI = {10.1126/science.6337396},
   url = {https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/6337396/},
   year = {1983},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
@book{RN41,
   author = {Knoepfler, Paul},
   title = {{GMO Sapiens}: The Life-Changing Science of Designer Babies},
   DOI = {10.1142/9542 },
   url = {https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/9542},
   year = {2015},
   type = {Book}
}
@misc{RN27,
   author = {Kornel Labun and Tessa G. Montague and James A. Gagnon and Summer B. Thyme and Eivind Valen},
   title = {{CHOPCHOP v2}: a web tool for the next generation of {CRISPR} genome engineering},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
@article{RN19,
   author = {Labuhn, M. and Adams, F. F. and Ng, M. and Knoess, S. and Schambach, A. and Charpentier, E. M. and Heckl, D.},
   title = {Refined {sgRNA} efficacy prediction improves large- and small-scale {CRISPR–Cas9} applications},
   journal = {Nucleic Acids Research},
   DOI = {10.1093/nar/gkx1268},
   year = {2017},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
@misc{RN11,
   author = {Lecun, Yann},
   title = {Deep Learning course at {NYU}, video lecture Week 6},
   year = {2020},
   type = {Online Multimedia}
}
@article{RN43,
   author = {Ledford, Heidi},
   title = {{CRISPR}: gene editing is just the beginning},
   journal = {Nature},
   volume = {531},
   pages = {156–159},
   url = {http://go.nature.com/24Nhykm},
   year = {2016},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
@article{RN45,
   author  = {Ledford, Heidi},
   title   = {{HIV} cut from cells and rats with {CRISPR}},
   journal = {Nature},
   volume  = {531},
   pages   = {156--159},
   url     = {https://www.nature.com/articles/531156a},
   year    = {2016},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
@article{RN5,
   author = {Mojica, F.J. and Juez, G. and Rodriguez-Valera, F.},
   title = {Transcription at different salinities of {Haloferax} mediterranei sequences adjacent to partially modified {PstI} sites},
   journal = {Molecular Microbiology},
   volume = {9},
   pages = {613–621},
   year = {1993},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
@article{RN7,
   author = {Opitz, D. and Maclin, R.},
   title = {Popular ensemble methods: An empirical study},
   journal = {Journal of Artificial Intelligence Research},
   volume = {11},
   pages = {169–198},
   DOI = {10.1613/jair.614},
   year = {1999},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
@article{RN6,
   author = {Patrick D. Hsu and Eric S. Lander and Feng Zhang},
   title = {Development and Applications of {CRISPR-Cas9} for Genome Engineering},
   xxvolume = {4.1.3},
   journal = {Cell},
   volume  = 157,
   number  = 6, 
   pages   = {1262-1278},
   year = {2014},
   type = {Web Page}
}
@article{RN8,
   author = {Polikar, R.},
   title = {Ensemble based systems in decision making},
   journal = {IEEE Circuits and Systems Magazine},
   volume = 6,
   number = 3,
   pages = {21–45},
   DOI = {10.1109/MCAS.2006.1688199},
   year = {2006},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
@article{RN46,
   author = {Rafal Kaminski and Yilan Chen and Tracy Fischer and Ellen Tedaldi and Alessandro Napoli and Yonggang Zhang and Jonathan Karn and Wenhui Hu and Kamel Khalili},
   title = {Elimination of {HIV-1} Genomes from Human {T}-lymphoid Cells by {CRISPR/Cas9} Gene Editing},
   journal = {Scientific Reports},
   volume = {6},
   url = {https://www.nature.com/articles/srep22555},
   year = {2016},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
@misc{RN14,
   author = {Ramachandran, Prajit and Parmar, Niki and Vaswani, Ashish and Bello, Irwan and Levskaya, Anselm and Shlens, Jonathon},
   title = {Stand-Alone Self-Attention in Vision Models},
   year = {2019},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
@article{RN16,
   author = {Ray, Tiernan},
   title = {Google's Supermodel: {DeepMind} Perceiver is a step on the road to an {AI} machine that could process anything and everything},
   journal = {ZDNet},
   year = {2021},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
@article{RN48,
   author = {Reardon, Sara},
   title = {First {CRISPR} clinical trial gets green light from {US} panel},
   journal = {Nature},
   url = {https://www.nature.com/articles/nature.2016.20137},
   year = {2016},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
@article{RN9,
   author = {Rokach, L.},
   title = {Ensemble-based classifiers},
   journal = {Artificial Intelligence Review},
   volume = {33},
   pages = {1–39},
   DOI = {10.1007/s10462-009-9124-7},
   year = {2010},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
@article{RN25,
   author = {Sangsu Bae and Jeongbin Park and Jin-Soo Kim},
   title = {{Cas-OFFinder}: a fast and versatile algorithm that searches for potential off-target sites of {Cas9 RNA-guided} endonucleases},
   journal = {bioinformatics},
   DOI = {10.1093/bioinformatics/btu048},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
@article{RN18,
   author = {Stemmer, M. and Thumberger, T. and del Sol Keyer, M. and Wittbrodt, J. and Mateo, J.L.},
   title = {{CCTop}: an intuitive, flexible and reliable {CRISPR/Cas9} target prediction tool},
   journal = {PLOS One},
   DOI = {10.1371/journal.pone.0124633},
   year = {2015},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
@misc{RN13,
   author = {Vaswani, Ashish and Shazeer, Noam and Parmar, Niki and Uszkoreit, Jakob and Jones, Llion and Gomez, Aidan N. and Kaiser, Lukasz and Polosukhin, Illia},
   title = {Attention Is All You Need},
   year = {2017},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
@misc{RN38,
   author = {Walsh, Gary},
   title = {Therapeutic insulins and their large-scale manufacture},
   DOI = {10.1007/s00253-004-1809-x},
   url = {https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/15580495/},
   year = {2005 },
   type = {Journal Article}
}
@article{RN20,
   author = {Wong, Jiecong Lin and Ka-Chun},
   title = {Off-target predictions in {CRISPR-Cas9} gene editing using deep learning},
   journal = {Bioinformatics},
   DOI = {10.1093/bioinformatics/bty554},
   year = {2018},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
```